# FireFox "Software installation has been disabled by your system administrator"

Tags: windows, firefox, permissions, firefox-addon, windows-7-x64

Installing Firebug in FireFox I get this error message:

> Software installation has been disabled by your system administrator

I am a administrator of this PC, how do I allow installation of Firefox addons?

<sub>Note: answering my own problem to help others in the future.</sub>

Comment: Note: not off-topic, because Firebug is a programming tool.

Comment: Thanks for nice solution but 4 and 5 steps are not required. No need to add in about:config Just follow below steps and Restart the browser. 1.Close Firefox
2.Open the C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla\Firefox\mozilla.cfg file in Notepad
3.Comment out the rule that is blocking it: 4. Re-open Firefox. Then Firebug will be appear in the address bar. Thanks

Comment: Cool, when you get 50 rep best to comment or just edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root cause is this setting:
[image]

This [blog](http://www.ryanchapin.com/fv-b-4-664/Fixing--quot-Software-installation-has-been-disabled-by-your-system-administrator-quot--Notice-When-Attempting-to-Install-An-Addon-for-Firefox.html) posted 3 years ago has a solution with Windows XP, the trick back then was to change this setting:

`user_pref("xpinstall.enabled", true);` in the file *C:\Documents and Settings\UID\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\fxlme5ka.default*.

---

To do this on a recent version of Firefox, follow these steps:

1. Close Firefox
2. Open the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla\Firefox\mozilla.cfg** file in Notepad
3. Comment out the rule that is blocking it:

> // Block extensions
>       //lockPref("xpinstall.enabled", false);         // prevent extensions

4. Restart Firefox

Comment: Great! Did the job for me on a corporate locked down Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

As a post XP update.

This disable property is now:
**lockPref("app.update.enabled", false);** You can also get to it from the *about:config* URL.

Also, if you are using the 64bit version of Firefox, make sure you look in the appropriate *"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" directory.*

Answer (score 0):

Open the `policies.json` file in a text editor, which is located in your Firefox installation folder. For example, on Windows, that is commonly `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\policies.json`

Ensure the contents of that file is as follows:

```json
{
  "policies": {
    "DisableAppUpdate": false
  }
}
```

This will enable the update mechanic in the following menu item:
☰ > Help > "About Firefox".